# How can I convert a Iterator[JsValue] into JsArray?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have an Iterator[JsValue] and need to convert that into a single JsValue. How can I do that in Play 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, it is just:

```
Json.toJson(scalaIterator)
```